# Create 2 buttons which change weeks (previous-next) using luxon

Tags: javascript

Im creating a calendar, but im having some problems with few things.
Like i said in the title i wanna create two buttons (prev-next) which when you click on next for example, it shows the next week.
Im using the luxon library.
Here is my code :

```
var debutsemaine = DateTime.local(2021, 12, 13).toFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
var finsemaine = DateTime.local(2021, 12, 19).toFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');

document.getElementById('c2').addEventListener('click', nextweek)
function nextweek(){
    
      debutsemaine = ?.plus({days: 7}).toFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
      finsemaine = ?.plus({days: 7}).toFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
    
    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Semaine du ' + debutsemaine + ' au ' + finsemaine;
    

}
```

i wanna simply add 7 days on my two variables at everyclick (and ofc -7 days for the prev button).

If you guys can help me ! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

By using `toFormat()` in :

```
var debutsemaine = DateTime.local(2021, 12, 13).toFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
```

You store a string in `debutsemaine` and not a `DateTime` object.

You can add 7 days to this string this way :

```
debutsemaine = DateTime.fromFormat(debutsemaine,"dd-MM-yyyy").plus({days:7}).toFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

But I recommend you to store `DateTime` objects and call `toFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")` when you need a string :

```
var debutsemaine = DateTime.local(2021, 12, 13);
var finsemaine = DateTime.local(2021, 12, 19);

document.getElementById('c2').addEventListener('click', nextweek);
    
function nextweek(){
    debutsemaine = debutsemaine.plus({days: 7});
    finsemaine = finsemaine.plus({days: 7});

    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'Semaine du ' + debutsemaine.toFormat("dd-MM-yyyy") + ' au ' + finsemaine.toFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
}
```

Also, if the default week is always the current one, you can get the first and last day of the week using [`startOf()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof) :

```
var debutsemaine = DateTime.local().startOf("week");
var finsemaine = DateTime.local().endOf("week");
```